# Translating from GPS coordinates to an address in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps, bing-maps

I have used the GeoCoordinate method to get a GPS Coordinates of a windows phone device, is it possible to translate those coordinates on another WP7 to get the address of that location??

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly translate data from one WP7 to another. 
 All what you need - it's simple `WebService`. From first phone you `POST` data (coordinates) to WebService. And second phone just check it whenever you want.

Hope it's help.

Comment: webservice to do that sounds great!!! but how can the second phone translate them??!!!

Comment: On second phone create app which can create GET Request to webservice. Webservice will return data in response (ex JSON or XML). And app need just deserialized data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bing maps reverse geocoding [REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx)